# Optimizing code for grouping by unique person

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization, unique

I have a file with transactions. Each transaction includes person identifiers (which are sometimes/often missing) and transaction data. Person identifiers are fname, lname, phone, email and social security number.
I want to link each transaction to a unique person.
As a business rule, I have set that two transactions belong to the same person if fname and lname are identical AND at least one of the 3 other person identifiers are identical.
As an outcome, I need to have two dataframes (and ultimately two csv files): one with the unique persons and one copy of the initial data with an additional column for the person id.

I have written code that works very well for solving the problem. Except that when the fils gets really long (I am talking hundreds of thousands of lines), it gets stuck. I am almost sure that my code is not optimized and I think I can find a better way using agreggate functions like groupby() or unique(), which I think are much faster. But I can't figure out how.

```py
import pandas as pd
workDir=r"D:\fichiers\perso\perso\python\unicity\\"


sourceFile='rawdata.csv'
inFrame=pd.read_csv(workDir+sourceFile, sep=";",encoding='ISO-8859-1')
personFrame=pd.DataFrame(columns=('id','fname','lname','email', 'phone','social security number'))
outFrame=pd.DataFrame(columns=inFrame.columns)
idPerson=0
#print(inFrame)


def samePerson(p1, p2):
  response=0
  if p1['fname']==p2['fname'] and p1['lname']==p2['lname']:
      if p1['email']==p2['email'] or p1['phone']==p2['phone'] or p1['social security number']==p2['social security number']:
        response=1
  return(response)

def completePerson(old, new):
    #complete with new line missing data in ols version of the person
    for theColumn in ('fname','lname','email', 'phone','social security number'):
        if pd.isnull(old[theColumn]) :
            old [theColumn]=new[theColumn]
    return(old)

def processLine(theLine):
  global personFrame
  global idPerson
  global outFrame
  theFlag=0
  for indexPerson, thePerson in personFrame.iterrows(): 
      if theFlag==0:
          if samePerson(theLine,thePerson):
              theLine['idPerson']=thePerson.idPerson
              personFrame.loc[indexPerson]=completePerson(thePerson, theLine)
              theFlag=1
  if theFlag==0:
      theLine['idPerson']=idPerson
      idPerson=idPerson+1
      personFrame=personFrame.append(theLine)
  outFrame=outFrame.append(theLine)


def processdf():
    inFrame.apply(processLine, axis=1)
    with open(workDir+'persons.csv','w', encoding='ISO-8859-1') as f:
        personFrame.to_csv(f, index='false')
    with open(workDir+'transactionss.csv','w', encoding='ISO-8859-1') as f:
        outFrame.to_csv(f, index='false')

processdf()
```

Comment: If you have working code that you want to be made better, consider the code review stack exchange.  Otherwise, please provide the minimum code necessary to get your point across. See [mcve]

Comment: @piRSquared thank you for pointing me to the correct forum. Just posted it there.